# Tracked Text Title renders "strange"

Tags: davinci-resolve, fusion

I am tracking a text object and sticking it to a certain point in my clip. This all work as expected, and looks good inside the fusion tab.

But... when I view this in the "edit" tab... the text becomes "blurred" when the clip plays. Almost like motion blur. All techniques and settings are used to get a basic text track working. Nothing else was fiddled with.

I have also tried to render out this section to file, and the blurred text renders to output file, yet is perfectly fine inside fusion.

Any ideas?

Resolve 16.2.5

**EDIT TAB**
[image: Edit TAB]

**FUSION TAB**
[image: FUSION TAB]

**FUSION PAGE**
[image: FUSION PAGE]

Answer (score 1):

The comb-like pattern on the text makes me suspect an interlacing issue.  There's a mismatch somewhere in the image pipeline regarding whether Resolve/Fusion is expecting interlaced or progressive footage, and whether or not it's actually getting interlaced or progressive footage.  It's hard to diagnose without knowing your settings, but look for options related to "fields" and make sure you haven't changed any from their defaults.  If your footage actually IS interlaced (unlikely if it's from a camera built in the last 15-ish years), then you would need to change these settings from their defaults.

Assuming progressive footage, in the Resolve Project settings, make sure that under "Master Settings,"  the "Enable video field Processing" box is unchecked.  In all Fusion Nodes, in each "Image" tab, make sure "Process Mode" is set to "Full Frames."

Another possibility is that the viewer is showing you an inaccurate preview.  On the Edit page, the viewer takes certain shortcuts to speed playback.  Exactly what Resolve does isn't documented, but it's likely to affect scaling, which might cause display artifacts.  For a more accurate (but slower) preview, you can disable "Performance Mode" under the "User" tab of the System settings, in the "Playback Settings" category.  If your rendered output doesn't display the same artefacts as the edit page, this is likely the culprit.  Setting the viewer scale to 100% would also show an un-scaled image.  Alternatively, viewing the image on the Color page will prioritize image quality over playback speed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The clip is HDR 30fps from a DJI Osmo Action cam, so it may very well be interlaced... It definitely looked interlaced to me, splitting between frames.. but as to why the fusion page would render it correctly, but the edit page AND output render shows it, baffles me. I have moved on for now, so cant really test further solutions. I need to try this text tracking again in other projects and will pick up from there if it happens again. Thanks for your input.